# Calculate two and 5 day averages based on another column

Tags: r, average

I wish to calculate 2 and 5 day averages for temperature and humidity based on the number another variable (stay). If stay is 0 (patient admission today) the average should be calculated from values of same date (day 1) and the day earlier (day 2). Similarly for stay 1 the average is computed from values going back 2 and 3 before date. For all values which have stay 8 and above, the 2 day average is calculated from day 9 and 10 before current date. The 5 day averages for stay 0 day is based on values of day 1,2,3,4 and 5. The following table shows how the calculation is derived.

Example output required.

```
Date    stay    Temperature Humidity    2d temp 5d temp
9-Mar-98    6   4.23        74.32        na     na
10-Mar-98   1   5.16        70.33        2.12   na
11-Mar-98   8   7.39        65.77        na     na
14-Mar-98   3   6.63        66.46        6.27   3.35
23-Mar-98   2   11.03       62.94        11.13  13.97
24-Mar-98   10  10.87       57.35        10.09  8.78
4-Apr-98    0   9.64        59.21        8.68   9.51
5-Apr-98    5   9.70        88.30        16.14  13.81
```

Some explanation: Admission on Mar 11 has stay of 8 and the average is set to NA as no values are available. Mar 14 has stay 3 and the 2 day average is calculated from values on Mar 10 and 11. On the other hand Apr 5 has stay of 5 and the 2 day average is based on values from Mar 30 and 31(the calculation begins from 5 days before current date).

The following table shows the time period for calculation of average from current date for each stay

```
 stay    2d average       5d averages
    0        1,2            1,2,3,4,5
    1        2,3            2,3,4,5,6
    2        3,4            3,4,5,6,7
    3        4,5            4,5,6,7,8
    4        5,6            5,6,7,8,9
    5        6,7            6,7,8,9,10
    6        7,8            7,8,9,10,11
    7        8,9            8,9,10,11,12
    8        9,10           9,10,11,12,13
```

Sample data found below.

```
> dput(mydata)
structure(list(date = structure(c(10294, 10295, 10296, 10297, 
10298, 10299, 10300, 10301, 10302, 10303, 10304, 10305, 10306, 
10307, 10308, 10309, 10310, 10311, 10312, 10313, 10314, 10315, 
10316, 10317, 10318, 10319, 10320, 10321, 10322, 10323, 10324
), class = "Date"), stay = c(6, 1, 8, 11, 27, 3, 4, 5, 11, 13, 
2, 17, 26, 6, 2, 10, 5, 2, 11, 24, 8, 11, 2, 8, 7, 30, 0, 5, 
1, 2, 2), temperature = c(4.23000001907349, 5.15541648864746, 
7.38499999046326, 9.47041666507721, 7.61999988555908, 6.62625002861023, 
8.71875, 11.4608333110809, 11.2570832967758, 14.5691666603088, 
10.3120833337307, 11.1216666698456, 11.1420832872391, 11.241666674614, 
11.03125, 10.8691666722298, 12.4862499237061, 13.9341666698456, 
11.8995833396912, 12.3716666698456, 12.5091667175293, 16.3833332061768, 
15.8945832252502, 7.26666665077209, 7.0091667175293, 7.73125004768372, 
9.63833332061768, 9.7045833170414, 11.4941666126251, 11.1304166316986, 
11.3908333778381), humid = c(74.3199996948242, 70.3308334350586, 
65.7658309936523, 69.2799987792969, 83.1170806884766, 66.4599990844727, 
67.4225006103516, 85.7504196166992, 89.9520797729492, 65.2566680908203, 
43.3604164123535, 51.7508316040039, 54.6866683959961, 68.2958297729492, 
62.9420852661133, 57.3504180908203, 66.4137496948242, 57.6333351135254, 
78.9029159545898, 84.5666656494141, 84.2004165649414, 71.2779159545898, 
74.0320816040039, 65.2512512207031, 58.8224983215332, 62.4949989318848, 
59.2054176330566, 88.2983322143555, 71.2545852661133, 78.0783309936523, 
51.9004173278809)), datalabel = "", time.stamp = " 3 Apr 2015 22:09", .Names = c("date", 
"stay", "temperature", "humid"), formats = c("%dD_m_Y", "%9.0g", 
"%9.0g", "%9.0g"), types = c(255L, 255L, 255L, 255L), val.labels = c("", 
"", "", ""), var.labels = c("     ", "", "temp", "rh"), expansion.fields = list(
    c("_dta", "_lang_list", "default"), c("_dta", "_lang_c", 
    "default")), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", 
"7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", 
"18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", 
"29", "30", "31"), version = 12L, class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please be aware that this site is not a code dispenser. Requests to write the code for you are generally do not received well here. Please take the time and over to the FAQ to see how to ask questions that will generate favorable answers.

Comment: I'd use dplyr windows function `lead`/`lag` http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/window-functions.html to add extra colums for the temperature for the last day, second last day ... and use `ifelse`for the case distinctions  e.g. `mydata <- mydata %<% mutate(temp_last_day = lag(temperature), temp_second_last_day = lag(temp_last_day, ...)` and so on. But there are certainly more elegant solutions

Comment: @ckluss I am new to R and the examples of the link are a bit difficult to understand. When I tried the code you provided I got error message " could not find function "%<%"". Am I missing something to run the code?

Answer (score 2):

can you give an example of your expected output, I'm not sure if this is correct

this is a simple loop. for each row take the stay value, add 1 and increase two (or five), then extract the vector of `temperatures` corresponding to those two indices, and `mean` them

```
mydata <- structure(list(date=structure(c(10294,10295,10296,10297,10298,10299,10300,10301,10302,10303,10304,10305,10306,10307,10308,10309,10310,10311,10312,10313,10314,10315,10316,10317,10318,10319,10320,10321,10322,10323,10324),class="Date"),stay=c(6,1,8,11,27,3,4,5,11,13,2,17,26,6,2,10,5,2,11,24,8,11,2,8,7,30,0,5,1,2,2),temperature=c(4.23000001907349,5.15541648864746,7.38499999046326,9.47041666507721,7.61999988555908,6.62625002861023,8.71875,11.4608333110809,11.2570832967758,14.5691666603088,10.3120833337307,11.1216666698456,11.1420832872391,11.241666674614,11.03125,10.8691666722298,12.4862499237061,13.9341666698456,11.8995833396912,12.3716666698456,12.5091667175293,16.3833332061768,15.8945832252502,7.26666665077209,7.0091667175293,7.73125004768372,9.63833332061768,9.7045833170414,11.4941666126251,11.1304166316986,11.3908333778381),humid=c(74.3199996948242,70.3308334350586,65.7658309936523,69.2799987792969,83.1170806884766,66.4599990844727,67.4225006103516,85.7504196166992,89.9520797729492,65.2566680908203,43.3604164123535,51.7508316040039,54.6866683959961,68.2958297729492,62.9420852661133,57.3504180908203,66.4137496948242,57.6333351135254,78.9029159545898,84.5666656494141,84.2004165649414,71.2779159545898,74.0320816040039,65.2512512207031,58.8224983215332,62.4949989318848,59.2054176330566,88.2983322143555,71.2545852661133,78.0783309936523,51.9004173278809)),datalabel="",time.stamp="3Apr201522:09",.Names=c("date","stay","temperature","humid"),formats=c("%dD_m_Y","%9.0g","%9.0g","%9.0g"),types=c(255L,255L,255L,255L),val.labels=c("","","",""),var.labels=c("","","temp","rh"),expansion.fields=list(c("_dta","_lang_list","default"),c("_dta","_lang_c","default")),row.names=c("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23","24","25","26","27","28","29","30","31"),version=12L,class="data.frame")

res <- lapply(mydata[, 'stay'], function(x)
  c('two' = mean(mydata[(x + 1):(x + 2), 'temperature'], na.rm = TRUE),
    'five' = mean(mydata[(x + 1):(x + 5), 'temperature'], na.rm = TRUE)))

cbind(mydata, do.call('rbind', res))

#          date stay temperature    humid       two      five
# 1  1998-03-09    6    4.230000 74.32000 10.089792 11.263583
# 2  1998-03-10    1    5.155416 70.33083  6.270208  7.251417
# 3  1998-03-11    8    7.385000 65.76583 12.913125 11.680417
# 4  1998-03-12   11    9.470417 69.28000 11.131875 11.081167
# 5  1998-03-13   27    7.620000 83.11708 10.599375 10.930000
# 6  1998-03-14    3    6.626250 66.46000  8.545208  8.779250
# 7  1998-03-15    4    8.718750 67.42250  7.123125  9.136583
# 8  1998-03-16    5   11.460833 85.75042  7.672500 10.526417
# 9  1998-03-17   11   11.257083 89.95208 11.131875 11.081167
# 10 1998-03-18   13   14.569167 65.25667 11.136458 11.912500
# 11 1998-03-19    2   10.312083 43.36042  8.427708  7.964083
# 12 1998-03-20   17   11.121667 51.75083 12.916875 13.419583
# 13 1998-03-21   26   11.142083 54.68667  9.671458 10.671667
# 14 1998-03-22    6   11.241667 68.29583 10.089792 11.263583
# 15 1998-03-23    2   11.031250 62.94209  8.427708  7.964083
# 16 1998-03-24   10   10.869167 57.35042 10.716875 10.969750
# 17 1998-03-25    5   12.486250 66.41375  7.672500 10.526417
# 18 1998-03-26    2   13.934167 57.63334  8.427708  7.964083
# 19 1998-03-27   11   11.899583 78.90292 11.131875 11.081167
# 20 1998-03-28   24   12.371667 84.56667  7.370208  9.115500
# 21 1998-03-29    8   12.509167 84.20042 12.913125 11.680417
# 22 1998-03-30   11   16.383333 71.27792 11.131875 11.081167
# 23 1998-03-31    2   15.894583 74.03208  8.427708  7.964083
# 24 1998-04-01    8    7.266667 65.25125 12.913125 11.680417
# 25 1998-04-02    7    7.009167 58.82250 11.358958 11.744167
# 26 1998-04-03   30    7.731250 62.49500 11.390833 11.390833
# 27 1998-04-04    0    9.638333 59.20542  4.692708  6.772167
# 28 1998-04-05    5    9.704583 88.29833  7.672500 10.526417
# 29 1998-04-06    1   11.494167 71.25459  6.270208  7.251417
# 30 1998-04-07    2   11.130417 78.07833  8.427708  7.964083
# 31 1998-04-08    2   11.390833 51.90042  8.427708  7.964083
```

Comment: I have edited the question and added required output. Your script does not  seem to consider stay. As an example , for the last row (Apr 8) which has stay  2, the 2 day average is the sum of 11,49 & 9.7(which are   3 and 4 days  the current date)